# How do I prove this using an injection (if needed)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm trying to prove the following:

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are sets and $A\subset B$, then $|A|\leq |B|$.

This is what I came up with:

Proof:
Let $A$ and $B$ be sets where $A\subset B$, therefore $A\ne B$. Then there exists an $a\in B$ such that $a\notin A$. Therefore, $A$ has cardinality less than $B$. Therefore proving that when $A\subset B$, then $|A|\leq |B|$. QED

From what I've been researching, that because $|A|\leq |B|$ is in this proof, that means I would need to use some sort of injection to prove this. Just wondering if anyone can give me any advice on how this would be done.

Comment: You don't "solve a proof", you prove something.

Comment: Hint: To make things easier to think about, enumerate the elements of set $A$ and set $B$

Comment: @crystal_math that works only if $A$ and $B$ are finite though which is not assumed here.

Comment: Not necessarily, one example is that you can enumerate the elements of $A$ with using only even number and the then the rest with with using only odds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately everything about this is wrong.

If $A \subset B$ then $A$ could be equal to $B$.  $A \subset A$.  Every set is a subset of itself. (this problem is about all subsets; not just *proper* subsets.)

You say that showing there is an $a \in B$ so that $a\not \in A$ means $|A| \le |B|$.  Well, let $A = \mathbb Q$ and $B = \{\pi\}$.  Then $|B| = 1$ and $\pi \not \in \mathbb Q = A$.  Do you want to claim that $|\mathbb Q| \le 1$.

I think what you were thinking was if all the $x \in A$ are *also* in $B$ then $|A| \le |B|$ because $B$ has everything $A$ has and more.  But that is *exactly* what you are trying to prove.

That is the intuition but you have to *define* the intuition formally.

$|A| = |B|$ means there is a bijection $\phi: A \to B$. $\phi$ is injective and surjective.

$|A| \le |B|$ means there is an injection $\phi: A \to B$ but $\phi$ may or may not be surjective.

$|A| < |B|$ means there is an injective $\phi: A\to B$ but $\phi$ is *not* surjective an there does not exist and and can not exist a surjective function from $A$ to $B$.

....

So you need to prove $|A| \le |B|$ means there is an injection $\phi: A \to B$ but $\phi$ may or may not be surjective.

....

And this is surprisingly easy:

The intuition is every $x \in A$ is in $B$ and $B$ has everything $A$ does.

So we are looking at each $x\in A$ and saying "Here it is! It's in $B$!".  So what function  *is* that?

Well that's just the identity functions.

Let $\phi: A \to B$ via $\phi(x) = x$.  That's it!

We must prove:

1) $\phi$ is a well defined function: $A \to B$.  That is for every $x \in A$ there is exactly one $\phi(x) = x \in B$.  That is true because $A \subset B$ so $x \in A\implies \phi(x) = x \in B$.

2) That $\phi$ is injective.  That is:  If $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ then $x = y$.  Well that's trivial:  If $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ then $\phi(x) =x$ and $\phi(y) = y$ so $x=\phi(x)=\phi(y)= y$.

And that's it.

By *definition* $|A| \le |B|$.

....

Now, I can see why this seems abstract or roundabout.  Or a weird definition of $|A| \le |B|$.  But notice.  If you are talking about infinite sets this is the *only* definition you've got!  And this is the only way you can explain cardinality.

That's actually why they call an injective function "injective".  Because it maps a set *INTO* another set.  And the must basic way a set can be *IN* another set is by being a subset.

Comment: I thought a proper subset meant that the two sets could not equal each other, that $A$ has all the elements of $B$, but $B$ has elements that $A$ doesn't?

Comment: Who said that $A$ was a proper subset of $B$?  You were only told that $A$ was a subset of $B$.  Nothing was stated about it being a *proper* subset.  But again. Even if $A \subsetneq B$ so there is $a\in B$ and $a \not\in A$ doesn't mean $|B| > |A|$.  Not without a better argument.

Comment: The proof I posted was "Show that if A and B are sets and A⊂B, then |A|≤|B|" Can I still use injection even though $A\subset B$ and not $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: If  $A = B$ then $|A| = |B|$.  If $A \subsetneq B$ then $|A| \le |B|$.  But $A \subsetneq B \not \implies |A| \ne |B|$.  Coutnter examples are $\mathbb N \subsetneq \mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z \subsetneq \mathbb Q$ or  $(0,1)\subsetneq\mathbb R$ where $|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Q| $ and $ |(0,1)| = |\mathbb R|$.... but obsessing on this is utterly missing the point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inclusion map $\iota:A \to B$ defined by $\iota(x) = x$. This is surely an injection $A \to B$.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't considering the infinite case, e.g.
$I=(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

There still exist $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r \notin I$ but  $|I| \nless |\mathbb{R}|$. In fact $|I| = |\mathbb{R}|$

So the argument you gave applies only to the case where B is finite. Now you have to think about the case where B can be infinite as well.

Your argument does apply to a few infinite subsets such as:

$\mathbb{N}= \{1,2,3,...\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{R}|$ is true. But as in the above example, this doesn't always hold for every infinite subset.